# Using one json file in multiple partials

Tags: handlebars.js, assemble

I'm working on a page that needs navigation at the top of the page and in the footer. The nav itself is the same bar a few class/layout changes so I would like to keep it in one json file. Is that possible?

At the moment, only the footer gets populated. I am using grunt-assemble to build the html templates.

JSON:

```
{
    "pages": [
        { 
            "linkTitle": "page 1",
            "subnav": [
                { 
                    "subNavLinkTitle": "temp",
                    "url": "temp.html" 
                },
                { 
                    "subNavLinkTitle": "form",
                    "url": "form.html"
                },
                { 
                    "subNavLinkTitle": "map",
                    "url": "map.html"
                }
            ]
        },
        { 
            "linkTitle": "page 2",
            "subnav": [
                { 
                    "subNavLinkTitle": "sub page 4",
                    "url": "#"
                },
                { 
                    "subNavLinkTitle": "sub page 5",
                    "url": "#"
                },
                { 
                    "subNavLinkTitle": "sub page 6",
                    "url": "#"
                },
                { 
                    "subNavLinkTitle": "sub page 7",
                    "url": "#"
                },
                { 
                    "subNavLinkTitle": "sub page 8",
                    "url": "#"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    {{> header }}
</head>
<body>
    {{> top }}
    {{> body }}
    {{> footer }}
</body>
</html>
```

top:

```
<ol class="nav-top">
{{#each nav.pages}}
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="has-sub-nav">{{ linkTitle }}<i></i></a>
        <div class="sub-nav">
            <ul>
                {{#each subnav}}
                <li><a href="{{ url }}">{{ subNavLinkTitle }}</a></li>
                {{/each}}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
{{/each}}
</ol>
```

footer:

```
<ol class="nav-footer">
{{#each nav.pages}}
    <li>
        <span class="section">{{ linkTitle }}</span>
        <ul>
            {{#each subnav}}
            <li><a href="{{ url }}">{{ subNavLinkTitle }}</a></li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </li>
{{/each}}
</ol>
```

Comment: I have done similar things with JSON data for navs, I think your setup should work.  Is static content from the **top** partial being included, like `<ol class="nav-top">`?

Comment: The top partial isn't being rendered at all. The content (link title, url, subnav link title) is the same but the html is slightly different for the footer.

Comment: Why do you think it's a problem with the JSON data, if no part of the header partial is included in the output?  Would the header be included if you stripped out the nav data and just put "Hello, Header" in the partial?

Comment: I don't think there is a problem with the JSON as it renders fine in the footer. The header just gives me `<ol class="nav-top"></ol>`.

Comment: Try putting `{{log nav.pages}}` in the top partial, does that output the page data to the console during the grunt assemble task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you have should work, but just in case, try referencing the file along with your partials:

```
{{> top nav }}
```

Then inside your top partial, just use:

```
{{#each pages }}
```

That's how I've done similar things in the past without issue...